# Getting Error: undefined: rego.ReadFile while trying to read rego file

Tags: go, rhel7, opa, open-policy-agent, rego

While I was trying to compile the code, getting below error. I have imported "github.com/open-policy-agent/opa/rego" but still getting the error.

```
-bash-4.2$ go build main.go 
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:20:26: undefined: rego.ReadFile
```

***Filename: discount_policy.rego***

```
package discounts

rule "Bronze Discount"
    salience 10
    when
        Customer loyaltyLevel == "Bronze"
    then
        Discount.percent = 5;
        Discount.message = "You have earned a 5% discount!";
end

rule "Default Discount"
    salience 0
    then
        Discount.percent = 0;
        Discount.message = "Sorry, no discount available.";
end
```

***Filename: main.go***

```
package main

import (
        "context"
        "fmt"

        "github.com/open-policy-agent/opa/rego"
)

type Customer struct {
        LoyaltyLevel string `json:"loyaltyLevel"`
}

type Discount struct {
        Percent int    `json:"percent"`
        Message string `json:"message"`
}

func LoadPolicy() (*rego.Rego, error) {
        regoPolicy, err := rego.ReadFile("discount_policy.rego")
        if err != nil {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to load policy file: %w", err)
        }

        return rego.New(
                rego.Query("data.discounts.Discount"),
                rego.Compiler(regoPolicy),
        ), nil
}        

func main() {
        // Load the GRules policy
        r, err := LoadPolicy()
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Policy loading error:", err)
                return
        }
}
```

**Note:** I have copied only the code which is required for this error as file is having long code. I can share rest of the code if required. I am new to *Go Programming*.

```
-bash-4.2$ uname -a
Linux dev-rh72-tas-1.in.intinfra.com 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I looked at the source for the `rego` package at https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa/tree/main/rego. It does not contain a `ReadFile` function; hence the compilation error. Where did you get the idea that the `rego` package has a `ReadFile` function? Also, your sample program does not have 48 lines so obviously the errors from running `go build main.go` came from a different `main.go`.

Comment: @KurtisRader It is from same main.go. As I have mentioned above that I have shared only few lines of code from main.go as this file has more number of lines. I can share full code please let me know if required. I was looking only for "undefined: rego.ReadFile" error cause, so shared that much peace of code.

Comment: In general you have to provide a complete, minimally reproducible example for this type of question. In other words: You do have to provide your entire program. Also, "It is from the same main.go" doesn't make any sense. What is "it"?

Answer (score 0):

That `discount_policy.rego` file does not look like anything resembling [Rego](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/). Where does it come from?

Comment: Here discount_policy.rego file contains GRules. The same file I want to read in main.go and test the same that rules defined is working or not but unfortunately got stuck with Readfile error.